# Spring Tool Suite and Spring Configurator - directory structure

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, spring-tool-suite

I'm wondering what is the best way to organize Spring Configurator directories in my Maven project ? I wan't to have prod,dev and test config sets with seperate *.xml and *.conf files.
And also I'd like to have a seperate master *.xml file that is used in every config set.

Do I have to place *.xml and *.conf files in seperate directories ? 
Or could I just places them in the same dir , like so:

```
spring/
  test/application.xml
  test/params.conf
  dev/application.xml
  dev/params.conf
  prod/application.xml
  prod/params.conf
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place them in a directory structure in a way that no redundancy exist on classpath. Eg: if your code searches for `*/application.xml` file and you have all 3 on the classpath it will cause confusion

Also leverage the use of [Maven build profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Configure it such that only relevant files are packaged for each build profile.